# Bug in firefox with setting disabled attribute to select after change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

On page i have two  with same options. If a select option it should be disabled in each select. Here is my demo: `http://jsfiddle.net/bfmKw/8/`

```
$("select").off('change').on('change', function () {
    disableOptions();
});

function disableOptions() {
    var $dropdowns = $('select');

    $dropdowns.find('option').attr('disabled', false);

    $.each($dropdowns, function (i, dropdown) {
        var mark = $(dropdown).find('option:selected').attr('mark');      

        if (mark) {
            $dropdowns.find('option[mark="' + mark + '"]:not(:selected)').attr('disabled', true);
        }
    });
}
```

But in firefox exist bug or feature. Steps for reproduction:
1) Open select box and choose option. Change event will rise and options will be disabled.
2) Open same select box, hover mouse on another option and click twice on diferent from select box place. Change event will be rised too.
If instead disabled set any another attribute all works fine. May be exist another way how can i disable options?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are saying is going wrong, but I think it is supposed to disable options that are already selected. It works the same in chrome or firefox for me.

Comment: its working fine what you want to do explain it...

Answer (score 0):

This wrong behavior appears after disabling selected option and only in firefox. Right disabling:

```
$dropdowns.find('option[mark="' + mark + '"]:not(:selected)').attr('disabled', true);
```